# Navigation dropdowns need scrolling capability

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I know that this question has been asked already but I know that there are many out there that have the same issue.  I may have twenty drop down menu options for a particular menu. Without having rolling capability, the bottom 10 menu options may disappear.

I found a fiddle that was already posed: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/2g5Uc/1/

Ignore the code below, refer the the fiddle...

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top visible-xs" role="navigation">
```

Keep in mind that the fiddle works in 'jsfiddle' but the rolling will not work when inserted into a navigation bar.

Comment: I don't see any drop-down menus in your fiddle - can you provide a better example of what you mean?  Also, I think this maybe should be moved to the UX site, where you are likely to get a better response, since this sounds like a user experience/design issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused to what your issue is exactly...the nav dropdown seems to be working fine. Did you want to have two separate drop downs because you have that in there but did not include an image or text for the second one. Overall it seems to be working fine, can you clarify your issue?